# How to auto resize the content inside a div in tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

My code is currently like this :

```
<div class="container h-auto">
  <div class="flex border-8 border-red-900 w-56 h-auto">
    <img class="h-autho w-auto" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/238/200/200.jpg?hmac=O4Jc6lqHVfaKVzLf8bWssNTbWzQoaRUC0TDXod9xDdM" />
    <img class="h-autho w-auto" src="  https://i.picsum.photos/id/65/200/200.jpg?hmac=pZrTO_F80X2VYUVpgorpj6xM_WABGhjIXYieK__8B50" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

which the images have exceeded the width of the div. I would like the images to auto reduce their size depending on the content inside the div so that they always fit the div. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I made three suggestions for you.

The first two are more specifically exactly for 2 images. Making them the same size with `grid-cols-2` respectively `w-1/2`

The last one works with any number of images, `flex-grow` applied to all childs of a `flex` container makes them all the same width.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container h-auto mb-4">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-2 border-8 border-red-900 w-56 h-auto">
    <img class="h-auto w-full" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/238/200/200.jpg?hmac=O4Jc6lqHVfaKVzLf8bWssNTbWzQoaRUC0TDXod9xDdM" />
    <img class="h-auto w-full" src="  https://i.picsum.photos/id/65/200/200.jpg?hmac=pZrTO_F80X2VYUVpgorpj6xM_WABGhjIXYieK__8B50" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container h-auto mb-4">
  <div class="flex border-8 border-red-900 w-56 h-auto">
    <img class="w-1/2" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/238/200/200.jpg?hmac=O4Jc6lqHVfaKVzLf8bWssNTbWzQoaRUC0TDXod9xDdM" />
    <img class="w-1/2" src="  https://i.picsum.photos/id/65/200/200.jpg?hmac=pZrTO_F80X2VYUVpgorpj6xM_WABGhjIXYieK__8B50" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container h-auto mb-4">
  <div class="flex border-8 border-red-900 w-56 h-auto">
    <div class="flex-grow">
    <img class="w-full" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/238/200/200.jpg?hmac=O4Jc6lqHVfaKVzLf8bWssNTbWzQoaRUC0TDXod9xDdM" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex-grow">
    <img class="w-full" src="  https://i.picsum.photos/id/65/200/200.jpg?hmac=pZrTO_F80X2VYUVpgorpj6xM_WABGhjIXYieK__8B50" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```